# Recommended Values for my.cnf - VPS: 2.33GHz, 1GB RAM

Tags: mysql, vps

I was wondering if these my.cnf values would be ok for a Xeon 2.33GHz VPS with 1GB of RAM.
There are ~5 sites on the server with low traffic and the server is running Apache/PHP/MySQL... Also I want to enable the MySQL query cache and would appreciate any advise re the amount of RAM to allocate to the cache...

MySQL Settings:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

key_buffer = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
thread_stack = 64K
table_cache = 4
sort_buffer = 64K
net_buffer_length = 2K
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Xeon with 1GB RAM? I guess you are using virtual machine, right?

Answer (score 1):

Some memory chache was set too small compare to 1GB RAM, even if you may use a virtual machine actually.
Performance may be better if you change some options and that won't eat too much resources.

If you are not sue what to change, take a look at MySQL recommanded configuration.
These files was located at /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-x.x/examples
Your configuration may belongs to my-small.conf, my-medium.cnf is better suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use **mytop** to analyze real-time activity of your database.

Also used **mysqltuner** to give you suggestions on your my.cnf values​​.

Too enables logging of **slow queries**:

```
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 3
```

The configuration of my **dedicated server** for a high rate of transactions if anything helps:

```
max_allowed_packet=16M
key_buffer_size=8M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
join_buffer_size=40M
table_open_cache=1024
query_cache_size=40M
table_definition_cache=256
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet=32M
max_connections = 300
query_cache_limit = 10M
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 3
```

I hope it helps somewhat. If you want to refer details about these(and many other) server parameters, refer this [Official MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html)

Regards.